# What causes CPU usage to suddenly increase when a program is closed.

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, process-explorer

I'm using the Process Explorer utility to look at the CPU usage. My CPU is running at < 5% for the most part. But when I launch a program (for e.g. Word, or Excel etc.) the CPU usage increases (for obvious reasons) and then the CPU usage again comes back down to around 5-6%. But when I close the program why does the CPU usage increase again? (It comes back down after a while.)

Comment: Many programs perform some cleanup when you close them, for example deleting any temporary files used, saving preferences, etc ...

Comment: *"But when I launch a program ... CPU usage increases (for obvious reasons)"* -- Care to list what you think those *"obvious reasons"* are?  I suspect your list is too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A program's choice of response:**

First of all, there are different ways that a program can be closed.  For instance, consider Notepad.

- If you start Notepad, and immediately tell it to close, then it will close.
- If you start Notepad, type something, save, and then tell it to close, then it will close.
- If you start Notepad, type something, and tell it to close, then it will show a dialog box asking whether you want to save first.

  - If you choose "Yes", Notepad will save the file and then close.
  - If you choose "No", Notepad will not save the file, and then Notepad will close.  If you don't answer, Notepad will remain waiting for an answer.
  - If you choose "Cancel", Notepad will make the dialog box go away, and Notepad will remain open.  So, Notepad can choose to decline to close, even when it is told to close.

Calculator (built into Microsoft Windows), however, will just close.  It won't ask questions first.

So, when you tell a program to close, or you tell the operating system to have a program close, the program may decide to respond to the request in different ways.  It is up to the program.

However, you may be able to forcibly terminate a program.  Basically, that just doesn't give the option for the program to close.  As an example:

- Running `taskkill /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"` from CMD.EXE (the command prompt) will politely request that all copies of Notepad close themselves
- Running `taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"` from CMD.EXE (the command prompt) will forcibly terminate all copies of Notepad

**Memory**

When a program starts, or needs more memory, it tells the operating system that it needs memory.  The memory manager, which is part of the operating system, will take some of the computer's available memory and reserve it for the program.

When a program is ended, the memory manager needs to unreserve that memory.  In other words, the memory manager needs to find the markers that point to various parts of memory, and change those markers so that the memory is marked as being available, instead of used up.

Keep in mind that some of the "memory" may be stored as "virtual memory" on a disk, instead of RAM.  With modern operating systems, the computer might decide to do that even if the program hasn't run out of available RAM, if the computer believes that the memory written onto disk will be left dormant for a while and the available RAM could be better used for some other purpose, like helping a disk cache cause the computer to run faster.

Once that program's memory is freed up, the computer may make additional changes to use that memory advantageously, helping the programs that continue to run.

*An example:*

This touches a bit on the topic of closing a program politely for forcibly.  I often have dozens and dozens of tabs open in Firefox (often slightly exceeding 100 tabs).  If I politely tell Firefox to go close itself, after the window is invisible, the program may still run for a while.  Then, if I try to start Firefox again, it may say that I need to close all other instances first.  I can go to Task Manager and see the amount of memory that Firefox is using, which can typically exceed a gigabyte (so much for "640K ought to be enough for anybody"), and I can just watch as the amount of memory used by Firefox declines at a rather steady pace.  Somehow, it seems Firefox is doing something with each tab that I had opened, and freeing up the memory that was required, piece by piece.  Then, after the number gets close to zero, suddenly Firefox just completely disappears from my list of running programs.  At that point, I can re-open Firefox again.  Alternatively, if I forcibly terminate Firefox instead of politely asking it to close itself, then I don't need to wait nearly as long before I can usefully start Firefox again rather quickly.  So, somehow Firefox is trying to do some clean-up of its own if it is given the chance to do so.

**Other task(s)**

If you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tasks, you can see programs that are running.  You can also see a list of processes (including "applications" that don't visibly show windows on the screen, such as "services") by looking at Task Manager or by running "`tasklist`" from the command prompt.  Clearly the operating system is keeping track of the programs.  Each program has a PID (a "process identifier" number).

The operating system needs to clean up after the program, ensuring that once a program is closed, the program doesn't appear in a list of programs that are actually running.

If the program had any files that were open, the file handles should be released, so that the operating system doesn't think that the program is still using the file.

Some of these details are describing features implemented by modern versions of Microsoft Windows.  There may be more tasks, which may depend on the operating system.  (Older operating systems, like MS-DOS, which did not typically multitask a bunch of software (but may have had some limited multitasking that allowed drivers to operate) might not even implement all of the functionality described above.)

**Summary:**

The above may not be a complete list.  A complete list will vary based on the operating system.  However, this does show that there is something for the operating system to actively do when a program quits.  Furthermore, programs may perform some clean-up behavior of their own choosing, and the details of that can vary based on which program you're using.

Comment: *"the "memory" may be stored as "virtual memory" on a disk"* -- You're confusing virtual memory and a paging or swap area/file/partition.  That's probably Microsoft's fault.  See https://superuser.com/questions/748743/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-built-in-memory-ram/748776#748776

Comment: @sawdust My first use of the term "virtual memory" is from swap files used by MS-DOS software, before I mucked with settings of any Windows implementation, so I don't tend to try to think of specific newer re-definitions by Microsoft when using that conceptual term. Still, I appreciate your effort. But if an application is stores data in memory using "virtual" addresses provided by the OS's memory manager component, & then Windows decides to map that virtually-addressed memory into a Page File instead of physical RAM, then how is that not a case of the virtual memory being stored "on a disk"?

Comment: *"how is that not a case of the virtual memory being stored "on a disk"?"* -- The contents of the virtual memory are stored, not the virtual memory itself.  It's a subtle distinction, but a necessary distinction that preserves the implementation concepts.  When you simplify the wording of the explanation, then you can come up with goofy ideas like   https://superuser.com/questions/1252621/is-there-a-hypervisor-that-allows-using-part-of-the-disk-as-ram