# Process Explorer CPU Usage pattern explanation

Tags: cpu-usage, process-explorer

The Process Explorer utility shows that my CPU is running at about 5% capacity. Why does the CPU usage suddenly increase when I launch an application and then come back down to normal usage (5-8%) a few seconds after the application has opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The operating system needs to find the program on the disk
- The operating system needs to create a process

  - You mention "Process Explorer" so I'm assuming Microsoft Windows.  If you ever do some reading up on SVCHost.EXE, that "service" is basically a technical workaround to get multiple pieces of software to use the same process.  That can make things less clear when troubleshooting.  On the plus side, this can have some speed benefits, because there is some overhead for creating a process.
  - Creating a process is doing to involve reserving previously-available memory.  Finding some available memory may require making some changes, like changing what memory is being stored in the Page file
  - A PID (unique "Process identifier" number) needs to be assigned to the process
- The operating system needs to have the program's instructions loaded into memory
- The scheduler will need to assign some CPU time to the program

  - In multi-tasking operating systems that run multiple programs, resources need to be shared.  So for a program to use a resource, such as time where a CPU is doing something that the program wants, there needs to be some sort of sharing mechanism.
- If the program shows something on the screen, then the window needs to be drawn.  That means the program needs to tell the "window manager" that it needs a window.  The program needs to tell the "window manager" what the window should look like.

  - For instance, does the program show a title bar?  If so, what is the program's title?  Modern versions of Microsoft Windows will typically show a program-specific icon in the upper-left corner.  What does the program's icon look like?  Does the program have a minimize button?  Do scroll bars need to be shown?  What else needs to be drawn on the window?
- That window will typically go into the foreground.  If another program was in the foreground, that program will need to become placed in the background.  The program that will be placed in the background will be informed of this fact.
- Then, the "window manager" will then need to draw that newly-forgrounded window on top of anything else that needs to be covered up by the new window.

  - The term "window manager" may be used more often in on Unix-type platforms, which may have multiple "window manager" options to choose from.  That might not be the most perfect term for Microsoft Windows, but I'm sure that the same basic concept is happening.
- Besides just the window, visible programs are typically also represented on an icon on the task bar, so that also needs to be drawn.
- Whatever else the program actually does will take some time.  Many programs will ask for user input, but will be busy doing something before the input is drawn.
- Why did the program start up?  Some *thing* must have requested that the program started up.  That *thing*, called the "parent process", gets informed.  For instance, if you typed a command at a "Run" prompt from the start menu, that prompt should be informed that the program started, so that the prompt can know that it may be closed.
- Really, there's a bunch of other things that need to be done

  - To get an idea, hop to a command prompt and type:
    `WMIC PROCESS LIST /FORMAT:LIST >> output.txt`
    Then, open up that output.txt file.  In between the blank lines is some of the data that the operating system will keep track of for every single new program that gets started.  On my Windows 10 machine, that command shows 40 different values for every process (every instance of every program that is actively running).

Again (similar to [the other recent question about programs closing](https://superuser.com/questions/1251006/what-causes-cpu-usage-to-suddenly-increase-when-a-program-is-closed/1251016#1251016)), the exact details can vary based on the operating system that gets used (or even more specific, like what patching level the operating system has).  The full list would involve describing a lot of the internal details of the operating system.  Reading entire books (like [Windows Internals, ***Part 1***: System architecture, processes, threads, memory management, and more / ***Seventh Edition***](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/windows-internals-part-1-pavel-yosifovich/1124331285/2677773938830?st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_Marketplace+Shopping+Textbooks_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP20452&k_clickid=3x20452), a book with four authors listed) would only discuss some aspects of what happens.  And, the specific details would be subject to change when Windows gets updated.  So, this answer is only meant to describe some of the tasks very broadly, just to show that there is quite a number of things that happens when a program starts up.

> and then come back down to normal usage (5-8%) a few seconds after the application has opened

To answer the second part of your question: After a program is started, a bunch of those "initialization" tasks are completed.  Whether the CPU usage drops or not will depend on what program you're running.  However, many programs will do very minimal work until a user tells the program to do something.  Waiting for input does not consume a bunch of CPU time, so CPU usage drops until you make the program need to become more active again.