# Do I actually have more RAM than I think?

Tags: memory

My computer has a total of 8 gigabytes of ram, although looking at the task manager, there is a lot of other amounts here and there. I do understand the idea of virtual memory and memory paging, but I was wondering do I have more than 8 gigabytes? Or are those extra amounts only usable by the system for example?

I have a whopping 15 gigabytes of committed memory, what is that, is that usable? Can I go beyond the usage of 8 gigabytes?

[image]

Comment: Similar question>>>https://superuser.com/questions/748743/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-built-in-memory-ram?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between virtual memory and built-in memory (RAM)?](https://superuser.com/questions/748743/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-built-in-memory-ram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committed memory also includes paging memory, so it can be larger than your real memory.

My own machine (16 GB) shows 26 GB committed memory. That is because of the availability of paged memory.

So, your machine is very most likely operating just fine.

Comment: That's good to hear, so going over the 8GB limit causes no harm, and is it recommended?

Comment: No harm at all. That is a normal situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I would be most happy if you would mark it as an answer

Comment: It didn't let me at first sadly, it magically says you need to wait 2 minutes now. I'll do so!