# Can small amount of tablet's RAM be compensated by virtual memory

Tags: tablet, virtual-memory, pagefile, windows-tabletpc, tablet-pc

If you have a 1 GB ram Windows 7/8/10 tablet then I assume there will be poor performance. Could it be improved by increasing the page file (virtual memory) size? Perhaps it's not so important to get a Windows tablet with 2 or 3 GB, if there is such thing?

Comment: The page file even located on a very fast SSD is still way slower regarding it's latency (may be a factor of about 100 to 1000?) compared to real RAM, that makes the whole system not only slow but often next to unusable.

Comment: The page file (aka swap area) is not virtual memory, but rather a component of virtual memory.  See https://superuser.com/questions/748743/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-built-in-memory-ram/748776#748776

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Windows feature called [ReadyBoost](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/usb-and-sd-storage-media-readyboost-with-a-sd-card-or-a-flash-drive-f19ab915-5f8a-b131-e6d8-a6900154a42c), which uses a USB flash drive, or flash SD/XD card, as additional RAM. That said, [its usefulness is questionable](https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/readyboost.html), because many flash cards are very slow. If you have a USB port or XD/SD card port on the tablet, you could try using *ReadyBoost* with an existing flash device, but you may see no improvement at all. Still, its easy to test,at no cost.

BTW, though [theoretically Windows 10 can run in just 1 GB RAM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-system-requirements-6d4e9a79-66bf-7950-467c-795cf0386715), I doubt that configuration would be usable. Most versions of Linux require less RAM than Windows, so if you have a poorly-functioning 1 GB Windows tablet, you might look into running a Linux distro, instead.

Comment: ReadyBoost cannot be used once you have I believe its 8 GB of system memory.  I forget if it disables the ability to do so or just indicates no benefit will be seen with it enabled. This fact of course does not apply to a system with only 1 GB  but I doubt the author actually has a Windows 8 or Windows 10 machine running with that little memory.  They don't even make 1 GB DDR3 and DDR4 modules.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, and even with 1 GB, I doubt *slow* flash RAM would help. Still, V555 can try it at  no cost. Personally, I'd go to Ubuntu, as I've done on ancient 32-bit devices (no later than 18.04 LTS, though. sigh). They're not *fast*, but usable on the road, and a minimal loss if lost or damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.
The 'virtual memory' is just a file located on the hard-drive, you will have "technically" more RAM, but at the speed of a hard-drive/SSD.
For comparison, SSDs speed is 320 Mb/s
RAM speed is 17 GB/s
You can see already how this will impact your performance, yes you'll have more ram but it will run horrendously slow.

Answer (score 0):

The importance of RAM memory is that the time of accessing it is very fast. Any program you open will be loaded from your hard disk into your RAM memory, including the data necessary for its operation, and then will be executed.

When you open several programs and your RAM is getting full, the ones that are not being used but are still open will be pushed into your virtual memory.

But virtual memory resides in the hard disk, that is a lot slower than RAM, and the performance of your computer will be hit while it is copying the program state from RAM into hard disk.

If you have very little RAM memory, or use very heavy programs, this interchange of programs residing in memory and residing in virtual memory starts to make your experience a real hell.

Virtual memory will never replace a good amount of RAM memory.

As highlighted by Francisco.l, the difference of speed between RAM memory and Virtual memory is astronimical.